# Register customer region to State/Province table

Tags: customer, forms, save, data, regions

I'm fairly new to Magento and I'm not quite sure how to add a State/Province field to the register.phtml form. I read somewhere that it's not a good idea to edit this file since it gets wiped whenever theres an update so I'd need some tips with that too. I've managed to add the field (by editing register.phtml) but after registering, the State/Province tab is empty in Manage Customers Panel.

So basically my 2 questions are:

1. What file do I edit to add a field to the register form?

and

2. What do I need to save the data in Manage Customer panel?

Any links or tips would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Collin

Comment: Still need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add an address to the customer with the following code in you local.xml of your theme:

```
<customer_account_create> 
  <reference name="customer_form_register"> 
    <action method="setShowAddressFields">
      <param>true</param>
    </action> 
  </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

[Thanks to Matthias Kerstner.](https://www.kerstner.at/en/2014/08/enable-address-fields-in-magento-customer-registration-form/)

Comment: I can't since I have less than 15 reputation